# What is working definition for female infertility?

Tags: genetics, reproduction

I've studied infertility and found that its quite complex to define. However, I came to know about a useful working definition of infertility; which was " Failure to achieve pregnancy".
Few days later I've hit upon a idea that proves that definition wrong. As I studied the turner syndrome, in which condition was XO but individual was infertile female. Further I studied that if they are subsequently treated with Gonadotrophin hormones, they have menstrual periods as well. There I found that if a fertilized egg is implanted in their uterus, pregnancy would be achieved. Now how would we call that female infertile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Infertility is defined as the inability to conceive after one year or longer of intercourse without the use of contraception or therapeutic donor artificial insemination.

That definition does not include a state of permanence.  That is, with treatment, fertility can indeed be achieved in many cases.

> You may want to consider the term **[sterility](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/sterility)** as a definition, which has a permanence to it. But even then, if you consider tubal ligation (female sterilization) or a vasectomy (male sterilization), then you'll quickly conclude that sterilization can be reversed.  At that rate, you may want to state **"irreversible sterility"** where a genetic basis cannot be overcome with treatment/intervention.  Even then definitions may vary.

As you've discovered, even some genetic-based infertility can be overcome with IVF.  In terms of your genetic interests, the condition of [XX male syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XX_male_syndrome), resulting from loss of the SRY gene during crossover, causes the inability to produce any sperm (azoospermia).  There is no existing treatment for that or even a reasonable theoretical one.

*This could get more complicated/interesting as new medical therapies mature.  If one were to clone a human for example, is that a type of reproduction? Likewise, there is gene therapy, which could overcome some types of genetic-based sterility.*

***Sources:***

- http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Infertility
- http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/sterility
- http://www.acog.org/~/media/For%20Patients/faq011.pdf